# How to set height in google streetview container

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I've been trying to get a google streeview container (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed) to start with the following streetview position (which is indoors at the first floor): https://www.google.nl/maps/@51.9158034,6.0661762,3a,75y,49.7h,80.68t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sZJt5xWlyFiAAAAQvOdRqJQ!2e0!3e2!7i10000!8i5000!6m1!1e1?hl=nl.

Any ideas how to get this done? The code doesn't seem to support a height parameter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #street-view {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="street-view"></div>
    <script>
      var panorama;
      function initialize() {
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('street-view'),
            {
              position: {lat: 51.9158034, lng: 6.0661762},
              pov: {heading: 80.68, pitch: 0},
              zoom: 1
            });
      }
      </script>
    <script async defer
         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you used the wrong link i think

https://www.google.nl/maps/@51.9181205,6.0705068,3a,75y,351.05h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sCMQYKN86IDwAAAQqa0k1Xw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=nl

You should also get an API Key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #street-view {
        height: 100%
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="street-view"></div>
    <script>
      var panorama;
      function initialize() {
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('street-view'),
            {
              position: {lat: 51.91812054, lng: 6.0705068},
              pov: {heading: 351.05, pitch: 0},
              zoom: 1
            });
      }
      </script>
    <script async defer
         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```